# UINavigationBar Height Change with swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, height, uinavigationbar

I have set my NavigationBar height = 65 in constraint.
When the device is in landscape position, the height is still no change.
I would like make the height in shorter may be about 40px.
I don't want to change or set to width.
I just only need for height of navigation bar.

How to implement this with swift?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried many examples. But not working for me. I don't know where I am wrong. Mostly, they write for width. I don't want to set default width.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change navigation bar's height.

If you want navigation bar with custom height then you can make custom navigation bar using `UIView` behave as navigation bar.

First you should hide actual `navigationbar` then take uiview with origin `(0,0)`, means it's x and y should be (0,0) and it's width should be `self.view.frame.size.width` i.e. same width as screen width and set height like 65 or 70 or whatever you required. Take buttons to behave as back button or else and take a label for screentitle in bottom middle of that view.

Comment: Please view my screenshot images. I put UINavigationBar to the view and I set constraint. When I rotate the device, the height is also 64. I want to set the height 50 when the device is in Landscape mode. Where should I write the code to implement this?

Comment: Take outlet of height constraint and then change it's constant to 50 when rotate the device.

Comment: can u please show me example of device orientation code?